# PDO: Bind an array to an IN() condition with multiple WHERE clauses?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, prepared-statement, where-in

Based on [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition/10722827#comment75974972_10722827)

The above question doesn't have any answers for using multiple `WHERE` clauses.

The second best answer works only with one `WHERE` clause:

```
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?';
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id IN ($qMarks)");
$sth->execute($ids);
```

If I put an additional `WHERE` clause, it produces an empty result or error.

```
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?';
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id IN ($qMarks) AND locationid=?");
$sth->execute(array($ids, ?)); // Also tried $sth->execute($ids, $location_id) and $sth->execute($ids, array($location_id));
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) accepts a single array of parameters. You need to do:

```
$sth->execute(array_merge($ids, [$location_id]));
```